# Caching object with hapi js - catbox

Tags: javascript, caching, memcached, hapi.js

I wonder if somebody has an example of hapi catbox (memcached or mongodb) to cache a http request with dynamic params, I want to cache the object that comes back from the server.

Comment: I got something to work using mongodb cache with catbox but I would like to see if anybody has some experience on what's the better approach for server side caching with hapi, would like to see what's better for a big payload considering performance and scalability between caching on db vs memory.

Comment: Could you please paste some sample code of what you have built by now? This would make your question more clear to understand.

Comment: I have similar plans. Did you work it out @FelixG?